# Servicestack Internal Prioritization in RedisMQ PriorityQueue

Tags: servicestack

I want to create a priority queue that has internal prioritization so that higher prioritized messags get popped first using ServiceStack. The ServiceStack RedisMQ implementation provides a *Priority* setter of type *long* on its *IMessage* interface. I would expect that message sent with a higher value on the *Priority* property would get popped first from the queue. My tests show that a message with *Priority > 0* gets put on Redis "Mq:MyDto.priorityq" while any other value put the message on the normal in queue "Mq:MyDto.inq".

This is some sample code illustrating what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
         using (var producer = MsgFactory.CreateMessageProducer())
         {
            var lowPrioMsg = new Message<MyDto>(lowPrioDto);
            lowPrioMsg = (long)1;
            producer.Publish<MyDto>(lowPrioMsg);

            var highPrioMsg = new Message<MyDto>(highPrioDto);
            highPrioMsg.Priority = (long)100;
            producer.Publish<MyDto>(highPrioMsg);
         }
```

In other words, I want the *highPrioMsg* with *Priority=100* to be popped before the *lowPrioMsg* with *Priority=1*. In practice, however, these message seem to follow a sequential FIFO principle.

Is there a way I can configure ServiceStack RedisMQ to work as I expect with internal Prioritization in the PriorityQueue?

Or is my only choice to either use the normal queue or the priority queue? In that case, why is a *long* used for the *Priority* setter instead of a boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [ServiceStack Redis MQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis) `IMessageService` implementation your right in that the **PriorityQ** is just another FIFO Queue and all that happens when you send a Message with a `Priority > 0` is that it gets published to **PriorityQ** instead of the standard **InQ** messages are normally published to.

Priority is a number so other ServiceStack MQ Providers have the ability to provide a different implementation, i.e. one which makes use of the Priority score. Currently PriorityQ in Redis is backed by a standard redis-server list which doesn't support prioritization of elements, eventually we may consider to change the implementation to use a sorted set which does allow sorting.

We also intend to ship different MQ Host providers for ServiceStack (e.g. RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, ServiceBus, etc) where we'll make use of the Priority score where the underlying MQ broker supports it.